# How do I display an array / object using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like the following:

[image: array format]

I want to display that using angularJS ng-repeat, showing both count and value for each.

This is currently the HTML and angular I have but nothing displays.

I also don't need to display the 0 index in the array, I want to start from 1 if possible.

```
 <tr ng-class="" ng-repeat="x in vm.data | filter: searchArray">
       <td>{{x.value}}</td>
       <td>{{x.count}}</td>
 </tr>
```

[image]

Comment: And whats the problem? Your code seems fine.

Comment: @lealceldeiro well as you can see in the second photo, the result of that html is blank, i can not see the values

Comment: The rows are being generated properly, but the values are not shown. I think there is something else wrong here. Do you have any error in console?

Comment: @lealceldeiro I have no errors in my console

Comment: Well I can create a snippet for you as sample with  your code. Also, if possible post the code of the `searchArray` filter. Could the problem be there?

Comment: screenshots are not a [mcve] of the problem.  It's not possible to take your screenshot of your console output and recreate your data for testing, and it's not possible to inspect your screenshot of blank lines to see what is being output vs what is expected.  It **seems like** ***something*** is being output, else why would you have lines across the rows?  Really seems more like some sort of CSS issue, but there isn't enough here to know for sure.

Comment: wait, looking at that screenshot again, it looks like your array is multi-dimensional? (array of arrays?)  You seem to only be iterating through the outermost array, which doesn't have any `count` or `value` elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went back to the basics and understood that an ng-repeat is just a loop in javascript, and what do you need to do if you want to access data in JavaScript if your array is multi-dimensional? well you do a nested for loop, and thats exactly what I'm doing in this case.

This is the updated html/angularjs that displays the data I need:

```
<tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="x in vm.data">
        <td ng-repeat="y in x">{{y.value}}  {{y.count}}</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thank you guys again!

Comment: James, you should mark this answer as accepted if this is the final solution to the problem.

Comment: @lealceldeiro Thanks, I just took that action so that others know this worked for me